# Where did sincos go? (gcc c)

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, math.h

Couple days ago it was working fine, but trying to use again today, my code editor cannot find sincos anymore and GCC throws me a warning that it cannot find sincos when compiling.

Here's the code:

```
// file: main.c 

#include <math.h>                                                                                                  
int main() {                                                                                                                         
    double sin, cos;                                                                                                     
    sincos(0.0, &sin, &cos);                                                                                             
    return 0;                                                                                                    
}
```

Using gcc:

```
$ gcc main.c -lm

   x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sincos’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    5 |  sincos(0.0, &sin, &cos);
      |  ^~~~~~
x.c:5:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘sincos’
x.c:2:1: note: include ‘<math.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘sincos’
    1 | #include <math.h>
  +++ |+#include <math.h>
    2 |
```

It says I should include math.h yet I do.
It says it can't find sincos yet it compiles and runs fine. I'm just annoyed by those warnings. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Have you recently changed form using default settings to std ones?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I haven't changed that but I did changed other things in my CMake file which probably caused it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the top of the file to enable the gnu extension:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <math.h>
```

This will prevent the warnings.  Note that this is a `glibc` extension and not part of the C standard.

Comment: To be clear, the `sincos` function is non-standard. It's a glibc-specific extension, not defined by standard C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Is there such a thing as a standard sincos?

Comment: @aganm No.  It's not part of the C standard.

Comment: @TomKarzes I mean is there an alternative that is in the standard? Or that is preferable to use over gnu sincos?

Comment: @aganm Right, I don't know of any alternative, except for one thing:  If you use complex numbers, you could create a complex number `n = 0 + i*a` where `a` is your angle, then use `cexp(n)` to get `cos(a) + i*sin(a)`.  It's a slightly roundabout way to do it, but I think it's supported by C99.  I don't know if it's any faster than just calling `sin` and `cos`, but you could test it.

Comment: `double s = sin(theta), c = cos(theta)` is a good, standards-compliant alternative to `sincos`. Probably your compiler optimizes it. For example, see the right-hand panel here: https://godbolt.org/z/cz6j2c (gcc -O2)

Comment: Re “Note that this will only work with gcc”: The fact that GCC supports it does not mean it works only with GCC. Do you have a basis for this claim? Do you know it will not work with Clang? Is it a feature of GCC and **not** of the GNU headers and libraries?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, I reworded it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In fact it's not specific to gcc. Its an extension supported by glibc (the GNU C library, which is distinct from the compiler gcc) and apparently by at least two other library implementations (newlib on Cygwin and musl). gcc is aware of the `sincos` function, so it can omit the call if the first argument is constant, but it has to be implemented by the library for a non-constant argument.

Comment: I suggest changing "`gcc/glibc` extension" to just "`glibc` extension".

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok I made the change.  I did see that `gcc` has knowledge of `sincos` (such as when it optimizes calls to `sin` and `cos` to a single call to `sincos`).